# setting min-height via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code I'm trying to use in order to set the height of a background div to always cover at least the background of the maindiv + the footer I have set up.

```
var bgheight = $('.maindiv').css("height");
$('#background').css('min-height', bgheight+'75px');
```

For some reason the code won't even apply to the #background div and I'm starting to run out of ideas.

When I do something like this

```
var bgheight = $('.maindiv').height();
$('#background').css({'min-height':beheight+'75px'});
```

The style is applied but the min-height is gigantic, like almost 50000px tall.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `bgheight+'75px'` ==> `(bgheight + 75) + 'px'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are making a string concatenation, not a sum.

Try this:

```
var bgheight = $('.maindiv').height();
$('#background').css({'min-height': (beheight + 75) + 'px'});
```

To ensure you are not concatenating strings, you can set `Number()` function.

```
var bgheight = Number($('.maindiv').height());
$('#background').css({'min-height': (beheight + 75) + 'px'});
```

OR (two parameters instead of object)

```
$('#background').css('min-height', (beheight + 75) + 'px');
```

Comment: Also, no need of using Object as param to css.

Comment: Well, no needed, but it's correct. Why downvote? Today, I suffer all the day unexplainable downvotes. I have a witch following my answers?

Comment: @Tushar `height()` setter it's not valid for this, he is asking for `min-height`

Comment: Just FYI, that's not mine. :)

Comment: Yeah, I know you don't downvote me, but I don't understand why today I grow downvotes with no explanation, and automatically after my answer, even when the answer is correct

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude some people have nothing better to do than downvoting with no explanation, but the reputation is not so important. What's important is to provide quality answers and help fellow developers write better code.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude The language. You don't have to worry if a single person is downvoting your posts, it'll be cought by bots as serial voting.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Bots are not infallible, unfortunatelly. Will remove my bad comment.